# AzureDevops Build fails due to Xamarin iOS SDK version

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-devops

We are currently having issues with AzureDevops hosted build servers when trying to build our application.

This is the following error we get:

> MTOUCH : error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void
>   ObjCRuntime.Runtime::ReleaseBlockOnMainThread(System.IntPtr)',
>   referenced from the method 'System.Void
>   ObjCRuntime.Trampolines/NIDCompletionHandler::Finalize()' in
>   'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'.
>   [/Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/4/s/Smartphone/......]

We have determined that this is an issue regarding the Xamarin.iOS SDK Version that the Build server is using.  When running locally on Xamarin.iOS SDK 12.14.0.114, the build completes fine.

Is there anyway to specify which version an AzureDevOps server uses?  I know you can use something similar to :

```
   /bin/bash -c "sudo $AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY/scripts/select-xamarin-sdk.sh 5_18_1"
   /bin/bash -c "echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=MD_APPLE_SDK_ROOT;]'/Applications/Xcode_10.1.app;sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode_10.1.app/Contents/Developer"
```

In order to change the Mono version.  What we really need is a way to select the iOS SDK version.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=designer&viewFallbackFrom=azdevops#xamarin ?

Comment: I have already seen this, this is to change the Mono SDK version, not the Xamarin.iOS SDK Version.

Answer (score 1):

You can install newer iOS SDK versions using the [Boots](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/boots-xamarin-ci/) tool.

Just install it, add the step to your pipeline and put in the installer uri you need.

The download uri is https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoTouch/Mac/xamarin.ios-13.8.2.2.pkg (obviously switch to whatever Xamarin.iOS version you require).

Answer (score 0):

By selecting the Mono version via the Bash script above (`select-xamarin-sdk.sh`), you set the corresponding Xamarin.iOS SDK version as well. If you use the latest Mono version (6.8.0 at this writing), you set the recent Xamarin.iOS SDK version at the same time.

See [James Montemagno's blog entry](https://montemagno.com/azure-devops-settings-for-xamarin-ios-13-and-android-10-apps/) about this.